# Remove blank cells in specific row until nonblank cell (VBA/Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file of some 500-600 lines (with great potential to grow). It started as an xml file and after an auto-read the table created has a varying number of blank cells between the header information and the remainder. The same amount of information exists per line. I need each line to contain contiguous data.

[image]

Imagine the yellow squares are cells with information. The top grid is how it comes to me. The middle is how desperately need it. The last is an ideal wherein the remaining table-formatted columns go away (also something I know how to do rather easiily).

I would appreciate any and all help.

Comment: So you just want to delete all cells that have blank data?

Comment: Ish. Either delete the cells until a cell with data takes the place in "C" or, if C is blank, reach for the next cell in that row that has text, cut the three cells, and paste it into the originally referenced C cell so it's no longer blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understand the real requirement, but if you start with data like:

[image]

and you select the cells in column **A** for the rows you want to process and run this:

```
Sub FixLines()
    Dim r As Range, N As Long, i As Long, RR As Long
    For Each r In Selection
        RR = r.Row
        N = Cells(RR, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If N <> 1 Then
            For i = N To 1 Step -1
                If Cells(RR, i).Value = "" Then
                    Cells(RR, i).Delete (xlShiftToLeft)
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

You will end up with:

[image]

Comment: This is good except in my sheet it takes out every column in the table with a blank in it. So the data I want move keeps getting appended--Even ones where the data is in the right place. I appreciate your help.

Comment: EDIT: It works!--but not in a table. That's a fix I can work with. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it (you could also use code to just move content to the left).

```
Option Explicit

Function Delete_Blank_Cells()
Dim lRow        As Long
Dim lCol        As Long
Dim LastRow     As Long
Dim LastCol     As Long

    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    LastCol = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).column

    For lRow = 1 To LastRow
        For lCol = 1 To LastCol
            If Cells(lRow, lCol) = "" Then
                    Cells(lRow, lCol).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
            End If
        Next
        If lRow > 5 Then
            MsgBox "Exit code - remove after testing!!"
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```